# How to create a JSON object

Tags: php, json

I am trying to create an JSON object out of a PHP array. The array looks like this:

```
$post_data = array('item_type_id' => $item_type,
    'string_key' => $string_key,
    'string_value' => $string_value,
    'string_extra' => $string_extra,
    'is_public' => $public,
    'is_public_for_contacts' => $public_contacts);
```

The code to encode the JSON look like this:

```
$post_data = json_encode($post_data);
```

The JSON file is supposed to look like this in the end:

```json
{
    "item": {
        "is_public_for_contacts": false,
        "string_extra": "100000583627394",
        "string_value": "value",
        "string_key": "key",
        "is_public": true,
        "item_type_id": 4,
        "numeric_extra": 0
    }
}
```

How can I encapsulate the created JSON code in the "item": { JSON CODE HERE }.

Answer (score 193, accepted):

Usually, you would do something like this:

```
$post_data = json_encode(array('item' => $post_data));
```

But, as it seems you want the output to be with "`{}`", you better make sure to force [`json_encode()`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) to encode as object, by passing the `JSON_FORCE_OBJECT` constant.

```
$post_data = json_encode(array('item' => $post_data), JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);
```

"`{}`" brackets specify an object and "`[]`" are used for arrays according to JSON specification.

Comment: i would add the `JSON_FORCE_OBJECT` in `json_encode($arr, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT)`

Comment: Is this correct?

$post_data = json_encode(array('item' => $post_data), JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);

Comment: what if I have an array somewhere nested inside `$post_data`. This would make them objects as well, correct?

Comment: echo json_encode(array('item' =>$post_data));
will create the JSON structure of: Object, Array, Object. or: 
{
   [
     {

Which is exactly what I was looking for, importing MySQL JSON response into an iOS app :-) THANKS Cristian!!!

Comment: You don't need `JSON_FORCE_OBJECT` when the keys are strings. It will always produce an object for this.

Answer (score 91):

Although the other answers posted here work, I find the following approach more natural:

```
$obj = (object) [
    'aString' => 'some string',
    'anArray' => [ 1, 2, 3 ]
];

echo json_encode($obj);
```

Comment: This response is so good. Also when you don't control exactly when an object is going to be encoded or if you want to encode an array of objects: then the JSON_FORCE_OBJECT response does not work. On the other side is much more readable. Thanks!

Comment: If you are looking for an encode that begins as an object and proceeds to contain arrays, this is your answer.

Comment: Actually for my case it converts into JSON string Object like this `string(36) "{"aString":626,"anArray":"OFZgavNT"}"` not like original JSON Object like below `object(stdClass)#27 (2) {
  ["id"]=>
  int(626)
  ["firm_id"]=>
  int(63)}`

Answer (score 39):

You just need another layer in your php array:

```
$post_data = array(
  'item' => array(
    'item_type_id' => $item_type,
    'string_key' => $string_key,
    'string_value' => $string_value,
    'string_extra' => $string_extra,
    'is_public' => $public,
   'is_public_for_contacts' => $public_contacts
  )
);

echo json_encode($post_data);
```

Answer (score 6):

You could json encode a generic object.

```
$post_data = new stdClass();
$post_data->item = new stdClass();
$post_data->item->item_type_id = $item_type;
$post_data->item->string_key = $string_key;
$post_data->item->string_value = $string_value;
$post_data->item->string_extra = $string_extra;
$post_data->item->is_public = $public;
$post_data->item->is_public_for_contacts = $public_contacts;
echo json_encode($post_data);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$post_data = [
  "item" => [
    'item_type_id' => $item_type,
    'string_key' => $string_key,
    'string_value' => $string_value,
    'string_extra' => $string_extra,
    'is_public' => $public,
    'is_public_for_contacts' => $public_contacts
  ]
];

$post_data = json_encode(post_data);
$post_data = json_decode(post_data);
return $post_data;
```