# jsonencode data

Tags: php, json

When I view JSON data as an alert when the page loads, I see:

```
[
    "Ankida Ridge Vineyards &#8211; The Vrooman Family Vineyard &#038; Winery",
    37.69603499999999,
    -79.17580859999998,
    "<div id=\"post-45\"><a href=\"http://localhost/jhtwp/business/ankida-ridge-vineyards-the-vrooman-family-vineyard-winery/\">Ankida Ridge Vineyards &#8211; The Vrooman Family Vineyard &#038; Winery</a></div>"
]
```

which passes on JSONlint. In my source data however, I see this:

```
/* <![CDATA[ */
var busipress_map_vars = [];
busipress_map_vars = {"default_map_icon":"http:\/\/localhost\/jhtwp\/wp-content\/plugins\/busipress\/img\/red-dot.png","default_map_icon_width":32,"default_map_icon_height":32,"active_map_icon":"http:\/\/localhost\/jhtwp\/wp-content\/plugins\/busipress\/img\/blue-dot.png","active_map_icon_width":32,"active_map_icon_height":32,"map_icon_shadow":"http:\/\/localhost\/jhtwp\/wp-content\/plugins\/busipress\/img\/msmarker.shadow.png","map_icon_shadow_width":59,"map_icon_shadow_height":32,"center_lat":-34.397,"center_long":150.644,"path_start":"35.7719444, -78.6388889","path_end":"32.7763889,  -79.9311111","locations":"[\"Ankida Ridge Vineyards &#8211; The Vrooman Family Vineyard &#038; Winery\",37.69603499999999, -79.17580859999998, \"<div id=\\\"post-45\\\"><a href=\\\"http:\/\/localhost\/jhtwp\/business\/ankida-ridge-vineyards-the-vrooman-family-vineyard-winery\/\\\">Ankida Ridge Vineyards &#8211; The Vrooman Family Vineyard &#038; Winery<\/a><\/div>\"]"};;
/* ]]> */
</script>
```

which is escaping the double-quotes (there's some other data in there that works fine). I have the following function that generates each location:

```
function busipress_business_teaser($echo = true, $zindex) {

    $location = get_field('address');

    $location_array = explode(',',$location['coordinates']);

    ob_start();
    echo '["';
    echo get_the_title();
    echo '",';
    echo $location_array[0] . ', ';
    echo $location_array[1] . ', ';
    echo '"<div ';
    echo 'id=\"post-'.get_the_ID().'\">';
    echo '<a href=\"'.get_permalink().'\">';
    echo get_the_title();
    echo '</a>';
    echo '</div>"';
    echo ']';
    $display = ob_get_contents();

    ob_end_clean();

    if($echo) {
        echo $display;
    }
    else {
        return $display;
    }

}
```

am I creating this data the wrong way? Using this withe Google Maps API v3. Thanks!

Comment: Why on Earth would you generate the JSON by hand? For all that is holy, use `json_encode` / `json_decode`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Create JSON-object the correct way](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3281354/create-json-object-the-correct-way)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your function should look like this

```
function busipress_business_teaser($echo = true, $zindex) {
    $location = get_field('address');
    list($lat,$log) = explode(',',$location['coordinates']);

    $json = array();
    $json[]=  get_the_title();
    $json[] = $lat ;
    $json[] = $log ;
    $json[] = sprintf('<div id=\"post-%d\"><a href=\"%s\">%s</a></div>',get_the_ID(),get_permalink(),get_the_title());
    return json_encode($json);
}
```

If you want to work with Goolge MAP they are enough PHP class to do just that

- [PHP-Display-Maps-using-Google-Maps-API-version-3](http://www.phpclasses.org/package/6588-PHP-Display-Maps-using-Google-Maps-API-version-3.html)
- [PHP-Display-world-locations-using-Google-maps](http://www.phpclasses.org/package/3801-PHP-Display-world-locations-using-Google-maps.html)

Comment: Oh wow - ok, getting a little nervous here as that's pretty amazing. So far, if I pass one one location to the JS, it works. If I pass more than one (stored in an array), my JSON becomes http://pastebin.com/xqUibs2v (I'm actually json_encoding the data (array) as a whole , not individually - should I not do that)? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: am not sure if this is the right way to add multiple locations in google MAP v3 ..I'll look around

Comment: Ok thank you very much, this is such a huge help. I've been at this for hours already

Comment: http://pastebin.com/NgnPdeTG That is my JS if it helps at all. Thanks again! JSON being passed into `busipress_map_vars.locations`

Comment: @Baba: searching for dupes, is cool, too!

Comment: @hakre whats just going through the Google API reference and documentation .. i guess that is allowed

Comment: I removed the un-needed `[ busipress_map_vars.locations ] ` to be just `busipress_map_vars.locations` in the JS and it works for multiple locations. The next and last part would be getting outside one more level", like so: http://pastebin.com/3JYEDY4b So I'm a little confused on that part.

Comment: @Zach just verified multiple location is allowed ... you can have something `$locations  = array();  $location[] = $json ; $location[] = $json ;` use `json_encode` for the `$location`

Comment: @Zach Seen your format ... that is not the right format ... the arrays should not have keys if not it would be converted

Comment: Yup - just saw that, corrected. Thank you so much!

Comment: @Zach you are welcome ..am glad i was able to help