# Convert MySQL Query Result to Hierarchical Data - D3

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, d3.js

As mentioned above i'm trying out the plot a chart using d3 where in i'd require the data to be in Parent Child relationship but i couldn't figure it out how to convert the MySQL query result to JSON parent child format.

Help provided will be very thankful.

I'm trying to replicate the chart in the below URL :

[Zoomable Partition Layout](http://mbostock.github.io/d3/talk/20111018/partition.html) (click on the partitions to zoom up or down the tree)

**Data in MySQL** :

```
Column1          Column2            Column3
First Top          -                  1500
First Child       First Top            500
Second Child      First Top            500
Third Child       First Top            500
First Sub-Child   First Child          250
First Sub-Child   First Child          250
Second Sub-Child  Second Child         250
Second Sub-Child  Second Child         250
Third Sub-Child   Third Child          250
Third Sub-Child   Third Child          250
```

**Desired Data Format :**

```
{
    "name": "First Top",
    "children": [
    {
        "name": "First Child",
        "children": [
        {"name": "First Sub-Child", "size": 250},
        {"name": "First Sub-Child", "size": 250}
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "Second Child",
        "children": [
        {"name": "Second Sub-Child", "size": 250},
        {"name": "Second Sub-Child", "size": 250}
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "Third Child",
        "children": [
        {"name": "Third Sub-Child", "size": 250},
        {"name": "Third Sub-Child", "size": 250}
        ]
    }
    ]
}
```

Comment: You have given us neither an example of what the data you're getting looks like nor what you want to convert it to. Without this information, all I can do is point you at the documentation for [`d3.nest()`](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Arrays#wiki-d3_nest), which allows you to nest data.

Comment: The sizes don't seem to be in your database. Where do you get those from?

Comment: That's just a sample data. I know with this data the graph won't be looking good. Help me how to get that sample data into the format what i've pasted.

Comment: Your sample data doesn't have all the data that's contained in the JSON.

Comment: Guess so that sample data is enough for now.

Comment: Ok, so you would need a recursive function which, given the name of a node, gets all the children of this node and constructs the JSON fragment accordingly.

Comment: Can you give me a example code please? Any other method you prefer in which data needs to be will also be accepted why because that's not the actual database. That was a sample thing which i prepared myself. I'm totally blank on these things i don't have an idea on how to do it. I prefer a working example code that's make me understand better as i'm a newbie.

Comment: A query like this will get you the parent/child rows: `select t1.parent, t1.item, size from tree t1, tree t2 where t1.parent=t2.item;` You didn't say anything about your server-side environment.  How are you going to access MySQL and send the data to the browser?  PHP? JSP?  You'll need to loop through the rows to build your JSON data structure; how to do that depends on your environment.

Comment: I'm going to use PHP. How will I be able to do it with PHP?

Answer (score 0):

Here's some pseudo-code, assuming one level of hierarchy:

- get the parent/child rows from the database (`select t1.parent, t1.item, size from tree t1, tree t2 where t1.parent=t2.item`)
- loop through the rows:

  - if parent is different than previous parent and previous parent is set:

    - push object onto array
    - start a new object
  - add child and size to object
- push last object onto array
- get root object (where parent is null)
- encode object as json with root object; see [Create JSON-object the correct way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3281354/create-json-object-the-correct-way)
- output json

Comment: I've got no doubt in querying the data from MySQL. I've got the problem only in converting that query result to the desired JSON format.