# Multiple entry in one mysql cell and Json data

Tags: mysql, json, angularjs

I have lots folder named as a some series name. And every series folder it has its own chapter folder. In chapter folder some images in it. My website is manga(comic) site. So I am gonna record this folder's and image's path to mysql and return to the Json data for using with AngularjS. So How should I save these folders path or names to mysql for the get proper Json data and using with angularjs.

My table is like this: Can change,

```
 id   series_name             folder     path
 1      Dragon Ball            788       01.jpg02.jpg03.jpg04.jpg05.jpg06.jpg..........
 2      One Piece              332       01.jpg...................
 3      One Pİece              333       01.jpg02.jpg...........
```

My current website:
[Link to Reader Part of My WebSite](http://mangayurdu.com/oku/One_Piece/789)

Comment: why store the paths to each image? why not just read the folders then display all the jpgs you find there?

Comment: @twentylemon My current website doing that with PHP. Is there way to do it with Angular? Plus I am gonna use this Databse for my website's android app too and isn't this proper way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you're using PHP on a LAMP stack. So first you would need to grab all your SQL fields and change them into JSON keys.

[Create JSON-object the correct way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3281354/create-json-object-the-correct-way)

Then you can create your JSON object like this and pass it to Angular when it does an AJAX request. Make sure you create the array before placing it into your JSON object (for path).

```
{
  id: Number,
  series_name: String,
  folder: Number,
  path: [
    String, String, String, ...
  ]
}
```

Here is the Angular documentation for an Angular GET request.

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http

EDIT:

It's difficult because of how your filenames are formatted. If it were formatted like "01.jpg,02.jpg,03.jpg" it would be easier.

You can use preg_split with the regex:

```
$string = "01.jpg02.jpg03.jpg04.jpg05.jpg06.jpg";
$keywords = preg_split("/(.jpg|.png|.bmp)/", $string);
```

but you would need them all to be the same extension, then you need to re-append the extension to each element after you split it.

There may be a better way.

Comment: I did some googling but didnt find it. How can I convert the data in single cell to array? I know other json encode part and all.