# Convert class object to JSON in PHP

Tags: php, json, oop, laravel-5

I am getting below Class object response at my controller in Laravel.

```
object(DayJibe\Core\User\Entities\User)#221 (5) {
 ["id":"DayJibe\Core\User\Entities\User":private]=>
 int(1)
 ["name":"DayJibe\Core\User\Entities\User":private]=>
 string(5) "admin"
 ["email":"DayJibe\Core\User\Entities\User":private]=>
 string(15) "admin@gmail.com"
 ["is_admin":"DayJibe\Core\User\Entities\User":private]=>
 string(1) "N"
 }
```

Now I need to convert this response to JSON.Is there any way to do this?

Comment: json_encode: http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php, and if you're returning this as a response from a controller look at: https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/responses#json-responses

Comment: Have a look at the json_encode function

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Create JSON-object the correct way](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3281354/create-json-object-the-correct-way)

Answer (score 0):

OK , What i did to solve this.
        $session = "Class Object as i mentioned above";

```
    $objClass = new \ReflectionClass($session);

    $classProperties = $objClass->getProperties();

    foreach ($classProperties as $propertie)
    {
        $propertie->setAccessible(true);
        $arrayForJSON[$propertie->getName()] = $propertie->getValue($session);
    }

    return $response  = Response()->json($arrayForJSON);
```

$response = "{"id":1,"name":"admin","email":"admin@gmail.com","is_admin":"N","generatedToken":"eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9
.eyJzdWIiOjEsImlzcyI6Imh0dHA6XC9cL2RheWppYmUubG9jYWxob3N0LmNvbVwvYXBpXC92MS4wXC9zZXNzaW9ucyIsImlhdCI
6MTQ2ODM0NjQ0OCwiZXhwIjoxNDY4MzUwMDQ4LCJuYmYiOjE0NjgzNDY0NDgsImp0aSI6IjU2ZTUzOTgxNTliNDA4M2I4Y2M5MmNlNWE4OGY0MDY3In0
.oLq6L8LM36n9KB2KN8asoKKfhVYOeBVUz1jjfjVGfL4"}";

Answer (score 0):

Tell the user to give you a JSON representation of itself.

```
class User {

    private $id;
    private $name;
    private $email;
    private $is_admin;

    /**
     * Gives a JSON representation of this user
     * @return string
     */
    public function toJson() {
        return json_encode([
            'id' => $this->id,
            'name' => $this->name,
            'email' => $this->email,
            'is_admin' => (bool) $this->is_admin
        ]);
    }

}
```

from your controller call it like so:

```
$userJson = $session->toJson();
```