# Creating nested json object using php mysql

Tags: php, mysql, json

Let's say that I have created two tables in my database:

```
`INSERT INTO `months` (`month_id`, `month_name`) VALUES ('1', 'January');`
```

and

```
`INSERT INTO `weeks_and_days` (`week_id`, `week_nr`, `day_nr`) VALUES ('1', '1', '1'), ('2', '1', '2'), ('3', '1', '3'), ('4', '1', '4'), ('5', '1', '5'), ('6', '1', '6'), ('7', '1', '7');`
```

What should be the correct PHP and SQL code to get **exactly** the following nested JSON:

`{
    "month_name": "Yanuary",
    "week_nr": {
        "1": [{
            "day_nr": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
        }]
    }
}`

I read a couple of answers and tried to apply them in my code, but I faild. I need some **simple** formula as I am quite new in programming.

Comment: Try to google json_encode(), it is a useful function that can echo what you need!

Comment: Yes, but I want to use first make the sql querry and then transform it with PHP.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of directly generating the `json` off MySQL, you should write the queries to get different values and put them together to generate `json`, e.g.:

```
SELECT month_name
FROM months
WHERE month_id = 1;

SELECT week_nr, GROUP_CONCAT(day_nr)
FROM weeks_and_days
GROUP BY week_nr;
```

First query gives you the month name and second query gives you the week/day info.

Please note that `weeks_and_days` table does not have any column for `month_id`, it needs one to map to `months` table (via foreign key).

Comment: Can I use `week_id` to map with `month_id`? What about the PHP code for the querries you showed?

Comment: @Rico11112016 you can't use `week_id` to map with `month_id` as one month will have muliple weeks. You need to have a separate column for this. For php code, have a look at this (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/383631/json-encode-mysql-results) and this (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3281354/create-json-object-the-correct-way) link.

Comment: how would the querries change if I want each `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]` as a **separate** objects, so "1" would be a separate object, then "2" and so on?

Comment: `SELECT week_nr, day_nr FROM weeks_and_days GROUP BY week_nr, day_nr;`