# Jquery DataTables: Data not displaying in table via Ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, datatable, datatables

My problem is that Jquery DataTables is hanging at Loading and will not display any data from the php script:

[image]

Here is my HTML:

```
 <!-- Default box -->
  <div class="box">
    <div class="box-header with-border">
      <h3 class="box-title">Time Management</h3>

      <div class="box-tools pull-right">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-box-tool" data-widget="collapse" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Collapse">
          <i class="fa fa-minus"></i></button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-box-tool" data-widget="remove" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Remove">
          <i class="fa fa-times"></i></button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="box-body">
       <table id="example" class="table table-bordered table-hover">
           <thead>
               <tr>
               <th>ID</th>
               <th>Clock In</th>
               <th>Lunch Started</th>
               <th>Lunch Ended</th>
               <th>Clock Out</th>
               </tr>
           </thead>
       </table>
    </div>
    <!-- /.box-body -->
    <div class="box-footer">
      Footer
    </div>
    <!-- /.box-footer-->
  </div>
  <!-- /.box -->
```

My Jquery Code:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable({
       "ajax": "api/timemanageprocess.php", 
       "dataSrc": '',
       "type": "POST",
    
    "columns": [
        {"data": "PASS_ID"},
        {"data": "CLOCK_IN"},
        {"data": "START_LUNCH"},
        {"data": "END_LUNCH"},
        {"data": "CLOCK_OUT"}
        ],
      });
    });
</script>
```

And my results from my PHP script.  I echoed the results from json_encode():
[image]

I've tried to use `"data": data & "data": json` as options in DataTable().  I've tried to put curly brackets to define ajax's options.  I've tried excluding `dataSrc=''` altogether, I've tried removing `type: 'POST'` and leaving it to `GET`.  I know my php script address is correct.   I don't know what it is or they are that is blocking the data from populating in Data Tables.   Could someone help me figure it out?  Thanks in advance. Help would be much appreciated.

### PHP

```
include ('../includes/sessions.php');

$select = "SELECT PASS_ID, CLOCK_IN, START_LUNCH, END_LUNCH, CLOCK_OUT FROM timeclock WHERE USERNAME = '$sessuser'";

$query = mysqli_query($dbc, $select) or die(mysqli_error($dbc));
$resnum = mysqli_num_rows($query);

//echo $resnum;
while($row = $query->fetch_assoc())
{
    $out[] = $row;
}

echo json_encode(array('data' => $out));
mysqli_free_result($query);
$dbc->close();

?>
```

Comment: so it is a post not a get? does this work?      ajax: {
                    "url": 'api/timemanageprocess.php',
                    "type": "GET",
                    "dataSrc": ''}

Comment: @BryanDellinger  Unfortunately, no it doesn't.

Comment: so you do see you have "ajax": "api/blahblahblah",  when I think it should be ajax:{url: yoururl, type: 'POST', dataSrc: ''}, the rest of your stuff

Comment: @BryanDellinger  I've tried that in the past, sadly the data did not populate into the table.

Answer (score 1):

Following Louys Patrice Bessette's suggestions, on the PHP side, instead of an json array, I turned the array into an json object. I, then I unquoted the options.  So instead of:

```
$('#example').DataTable({
    "ajax": "url", 
    "columns" : [
        {"data": "keyname"},
        {"data": "keyname"},
    ]
})
```

I did:

```
$('#example').DataTable({
    ajax: "url", 
    columns : [
       {"data": "keyname"},
       {"data": "keyname"},
    ]
})
```

I also removed the `dataSrc` option too.

Answer (score 0):

In the json you receive, there is no `data` property.

If you can modify how the json is generated, place all your objects in a `data` object... Like in the example provided in [their documentation](https://datatables.net/examples/ajax/objects.html):

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "name": "Tiger Nixon",
      "position": "System Architect",
      "salary": "$320,800",
      "start_date": "2011/04/25",
      "office": "Edinburgh",
      "extn": "5421"
    },
    /...
```

Or, if you cannot modify the json, try something like this: *(I didn't test this... You have to try)*

```
"columns": [
    {"PASS_ID"},
    {"CLOCK_IN"},
    {"START_LUNCH"},
    {"END_LUNCH"},
    {"CLOCK_OUT"}
]
```

---

**EDIT**

Just to make sure the json has no issue...
Try to request it from another ajax request (Just as a test):

```
$.ajax({
  url: "api/timemanageprocess.php",
  method: "post",
  dataType: "json",
  success: function(response){
    console.log( JSON.stringify(response) );
  },
  error: function(request, status, errorThrown){
    console.log(errorThrown);
  }
});
```

If that result is ok, we'll investigate around Datatable.
The idea is to narrow the problem...
;)

Comment: I've turned my array into a data object by using <a href="https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3281354/create-json-object-the-correct-way">this</a> and Data Tables is not recognizing the newly formatted information.   I've also tried your second possible solution, it doesn't work.

Comment: Well, the data did return in the console.log through regular ajax.

Comment: Good. And was it structured as it should? (with the "data" array of objects ?

Comment: yes. it was. looked like this: {"data":[{"PASS_ID":"5","CLOCK_IN":"2017-08-10 23:27:13","START_LUNCH":"2017-08-12 12:58:59","END_LUNCH":"0000-00-00 00:00:00","CLOCK_OUT":"0000-00-00 00:00:00"}.....}]}

Comment: ok... Try to remove `dataSrc:'',`... Because It is supposed to [*«...defines the property from the data source object to read»*](https://datatables.net/reference/option/ajax.dataSrc). So I maybe this "empty" definition may has an effect.

Comment: I wanted to thank you for helping me out.  I appreciate it!   Removing dataSrc and the double quotes around ajax and columns, actually populated the table, oddly.   Not at all like what the examples on Data Tables's website.

Comment: You can answer yourself, to post exactly what fixed your issue in detail. It could be usefull to some future readers. ;) Glad I helped you find it.