# PHP UrlEncode and UrlDecode are not accepting the word NULL in an SQL String submitted with GUZZLE

Tags: php, guzzle

So I'm passing in a Query where there is the condition

> where X is NULL

is the condition at the end of the SQL.... it is using

> "{"query":"".urlencode($this->query)."","ods":"" .
> urlencode(serialize($this->ods)) .
> "","key":"".getenv('ODS_COURSE_INTERNAL_API_KEY').""}"

in the GUZZLE to post the query and some other things to a backend API.

Fails and nothing shows up at the backend but says the call is successful.....

When I remove the ***NULL*** it runs fine and returns data. I also ran the query in SQLDeveloper and the query returns data with and without the NULL.....

Thoughts?

Comment: It is a bit hard to understand the question - is the blockquoted text you have here including `urlencode($this->query)` actually your code?  And you are somehow passing that to Guzzle as a request body?  What do you mean exactly by "*are not accepting the word NULL*" - that you get no results for that query?  "*When I remove the NULL*" - I guess this means you remove that whole `where X is NULL` condition, not literally just the word `NULL`?  Is it possible that there really are no results matching that condition?  Are you able to view the query as received on the remote backend?

Comment: One observation - it looks like you are manually building a JSON string, which is almost always a bad idea.  It is unlikely that's the problem here, but why risk it, [use `json_encode()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3281354/how-to-create-a-json-object).  How are you passing that JSON string to Guzzle?

Comment: Also the quoting on that JSON is completely broken because none of the quotes are escaped.